# Adding table to database dynamically in runtime Entityframework core c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-migrations

I'm looking for a way to add table to database in runtime with entityframework core, i would like to use `ModelBuilder` or `MigrationBuilder` but I can't reach these class via Action method in controller i don't want to use `OnModelCreating` because it will run only one time once the application is executed, is there any solution to add table to database dynamically without need to do the following steps manual "stop the running of the application and add manually a class to modals and do 'add-migration' then the 'update-database'" ?

Comment: No  there is not.

Comment: @ErikEJ there no other suggested approch for that ?

Comment: Use ADO.NET and strings, EF Core was designed for strongly typed classes

Comment: @ErikEJ yeah i'm thinking in this way and also i can made class dynamically using some other approaches, I'll do answer my question here if i really found something that fit my needs... thank you

Comment: Why do you need new tables? You will not be able to write linq queries to dynamically created tables. Meanwhile, they are the whole power of EF. Probably you need to store data in arbitrary formats. Try JSON or XML type columns for this.